Remove variable label when using tbl_strata() and tbl_summary() from gtsummary package
I would like to use tbl_summary() and tbl_strata() to create a summary table:
library(gtsummary)
library(ggplot2)

data("mpg")

mpg |> 
  select(hwy, cyl, manufacturer) |> 
  tbl_strata(strata = manufacturer, ~ .x |> 
               tbl_summary(by = cyl, type = list("hwy" ~ "continuous")),
             .combine_with = "tbl_stack")


But I would like to omit the "hwy" label and just use "manufacturer" as label, in order to get rid of the many blank rows. Is that possible?

This is very similar to the second example in the help file for ?tbl_strata.

You will want to use .combine_args = list(group_header = NULL) to suppress the default stacked headers.
Update to tbl_strata2() which passes the strata level as a second argument, and add this line to update the label label = list(hwy = .y)

library(gtsummary)
packageVersion("gtsummary")
#> [1] '1.7.2'

data("mpg", package = "ggplot2")

mpg |>
  select(hwy, cyl, manufacturer) |>
  tbl_strata2(
    strata = manufacturer,
    ~ .x |>
      tbl_summary(
        by = cyl,
        type = list(hwy = "continuous"),
        label = list(hwy = .y)
      ),
    .combine_with = "tbl_stack",
    .combine_args = list(group_header = NULL)
  ) |> 
  as_kable() # convert to kable to display on SO
#> ℹ Column headers among stacked tables differ. Headers from the first table are
#> used. Use `quiet = TRUE` to suppress this message.




Characteristic
4, N = 8
6, N = 9
8, N = 1




audi
29 (27, 29)
25 (25, 26)
23 (23, 23)


chevrolet
29 (28, 29)
26 (26, 28)
20 (17, 24)


dodge
24 (24, 24)
22 (18, 23)
16 (15, 17)


ford
19 (17, 25)
17 (17, 21)



honda
32 (32, 34)




hyundai
28 (27, 29)
25 (24, 26)



jeep
20 (20, 21)
17 (14, 18)



land rover
17 (15, 18)




lincoln
17 (17, 18)




mercury
18 (18, 19)
18 (18, 19)



nissan
30 (29, 31)
25 (19, 26)
18 (18, 18)


pontiac
27 (26, 27)
25 (25, 25)



subaru
26 (25, 26)




toyota
30 (23, 31)
20 (19, 26)
17 (16, 18)


volkswagen
29 (29, 29)
29 (29, 29)
25 (24, 26)



Created on 2024-04-12 with reprex v2.1.0
